# Error in Creating of DB Link from Oracle to SQL server

Tags: database, oracle

I am trying to create db link from Oracle to SQL Server. For this I followed the following steps:

1. List item
2. I created the Odbc configuration and tested it successfully.
3. I created the heterogeneous service init.
4. I modified Listener.ora and Tnsnames.ora files.

And then I created db `link(name:HSLADKRABANG.KRFT.NET)`. Now when I am trying to test it, it gives a following error:

An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

```
ORA-28545: error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to an agent
Unable to retrieve text of NETWORK/NCR message 65535
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from HSLADKRABANG.KRFT.NET


28545. 0000 -  "error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to an agent"


*Cause:    An attempt to call an external procedure or to issue SQL
       to a non-Oracle system on a Heterogeneous Services database 
link
       failed at connection initialization.  The error diagnosed
       by Net8 NCR software is reported separately.
*Action:   Refer to the Net8 NCRO error message.  If this isn't clear,
       check connection administrative setup in tnsnames.ora
       and listener.ora for the service associated with the
       Heterogeneous Services database link being used, or with
       'extproc_connection_data' for an external procedure call.


Vendor code 28545
```

I believe listener and tnsnames files are valid.

Also I tried to tns ping the listener, it gave error TNS:no listener.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the command you used to create DB link from Oracle to SQLServer? Also, when you mentioned TNSPING, did you use it to ping SQLServer? Have you tried any other options? Like a JAVA stored connection from Oracle to SQLServer?

Comment: Command for db link: CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK HSLADKRABANG.KRFT.NET 
CONNECT TO Username IDENTIFIED BY "***" 
USING 'HSLADKRABANG.krft.net';

Comment: Are you sure you can use Oracle DB link to connect to SQLSERVER? I have not heard of it before. However, you can create JAVA Stored database connections with Oracle to connect external databases where DBLINK is prohibited/doesn't work.